# Plotting a Silverlight line/area graph by getting data from SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, silverlight, graph

I'm very new to Silverlight and programming in general so help me out here.

I want to plot a Silverlight line/area graph by getting it's coordinates from a database when the user enters some data. The graph will change its value (by pressing refresh on the browser) when the value in the database changes according to what the user enters. I wish to implement this graph (or application) in a HTML environment, like Expression Web.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 .NET 3.5 and C# to do my Silverlight application and SQL Server 2008 for my database. Using Visifire is out of the question. Anyone to give me a head start? Thanks.

**Bao**

Comment: Please ask one question, in a question.  If you want to know how to globalise a Silverlight app (after first checking for similar quesions) ask that as a separate question.  Edit this question to relate only to binding an SL chart to data in a SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the [Silverlight Toolkit Charts](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%202), bound to data pulled from a webservice. There are a lot of ways to pull data via webservice, such as [ADO.NET Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838234(VS.95).aspx).

Here's [a blog post about how to do that](http://blogs.msdn.com/phaniraj/archive/2009/06/11/silverlight-toolkit-with-ado-net-data-services-drill-down-charts-using-astoria.aspx), with an attached project zip file.

Comment: What about LinQ to SQL? Are there any tutorials regarding graph creation in regards to LinQ to SQL? I can't seem to find any.

Comment: Linq to Sql is a server side technology, it can't be used from SL directly.  However you could take Jon's advice about using ADO.NET Data Services to connect SL to your server, then use Linq to Sql on the server side to get the data and return it to SL.

Comment: Erm that sounds really complicated lol. Any sources that I can refer to? Thanks.

Comment: Hey Jon thanks for the link, but when I try to run the application my browser shows nothing. Any ideas? Thanks.